Adding "test" target config to existing NX libraries
I am working on an application that uses https://nx.dev/ and https://angular.dev/ and is configured with https://jestjs.io/ to run unit tests.
I normally use this command to generate new Angular libraries inside the project:
npx nx generate @nx/angular:library

When selecting "jest" as unitTestRunner (which is our default), it correctly configures the project.json with a "test" target as well as adding the necessary configuration files for unit testing (e.g. tsconfig.spec.json, jest.config.ts, test-setup.ts and a placeholder test).
Unfortunately, many of the existing libraries in the project were generated without the test target and I would like to add them programmatically.
How can I achieve that?
In other words, I need a way to generate the testing configuration (i.e. change project.json with a "test" target and add the configuration files tsconfig.spec.json, jest.config.ts, test-setup.ts) for all the libraries that currently do not have any "test" target.

With this command ? => nx g @nx/jest:configuration --project=

that adds the standard Jest config but unfortunately not the Angular presets that @nx/angular:library would add instead.
